# Enabling quota and doing quotacheck on reboot

Tags: quota, disk-space-utilization

I have setup quota for home directories on ubuntu 10.04 server. I followed these tutorials: [5 Steps to Setup User and Group Disk Quota](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/disk-quota/) and [Disk Quota](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disk_Quota) This code I used at fstab file:

> /dev/sda1 /home ext4
>   defaults,usrjquota=aquota.user,grpjquota=aquota.grp,jqfmt=vfsv0
>   1 1

I have doubts about whether following steps are necessary:
Adding `quotaon -a >/dev/null 2>&1` to `/etc/rc.local` and adding `quotacheck -avug` to `/etc/cron.daily/quotacheck`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu takes care of installing the startup script and periodic quota warnings. Look at the [filelist of the `quota` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/i386/quota/filelist), `/etc/init.d/quota` turns quotas on:

```
on=/sbin/quotaon
# snip
ALLFLAGS=-aug
# snip
$on $ALLFLAGS
```

The cron file at `/etc/cron.daily/quota` runs `/usr/sbin/warnquota`. Note that quota's are working realtime, `warnquota` mails the user if they've [exceeded their soft limit](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man8/warnquota.8.html).

Comment: quotacheck and warnquota are two different things ! The first one checks if the quota files are not corrupted.